# How to simply respond to a dialogflow webhook fullfilment based on the parameters and intent that is sent

Tags: node.js, webhooks, dialogflow-es, fulfillment

I'm quite new to nodeJS and I want to know how could I make a server that will respond to dialogflow's webhook fulfillment based on the intents and the parameters in dialogflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would encourage you to follow this [Actions Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/). It would help you setup your webhook deployment on your local environment.
Then follow [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#5) to parse parameters in your fulfillment.

Hope that helps !