# What is the DialogFlow webhook response URL

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I created a V2 agent that makes a **DialogFlow** webhook for one of my intents. I receive the webhook in my server code but I'm not sure how to respond to it. I can't find the URL I need to make the response back as well the authentication or other info needed to associate my response to the original webhook request.
I'm using Python in a custom app to respond. Does anyone know where I can find this information?

I've looked through the following documentation, and more:

- https://developers.google.com/actions/build/json/dialogflow-webhook-json
- https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#webhookresponse
- https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-json/tree/master/responses/v2/ActionsOnGoogle
- https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/fulfillment
- [How to simply respond to a dialogflow webhook fullfilment based on the parameters and intent that is sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458276/how-to-simply-respond-to-a-dialogflow-webhook-fullfilment-based-on-the-parameter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an end-point to respond to webhook requests. You just need to return a response from the webhook in a proper format which your dialogflow agent is expecting. Dialogflow agent will be able to map it to correct request based on `responseId` which it sends with the request.

Suppose, you got a webhook request in your python app :

> req = {'responseId': 'f8vaj49u-10i8-49c1-8491-8ac491e84918', 'queryResult':
>   {'queryText': 'how are you doing', 'parameters': {},
>   'allRequiredParamsPresent': True, 'fulfillmentText': 'Wonderful!
>   Thanks for asking.', 'fulfillmentMessages': [{'text': {'text':
>   ['Wonderful! Thanks for asking.']}}], 'intent': {'name':
>   'projects/agent_name/agent/intents/########', 'displayName':
>   'smalltalk.greetings.how_are_you'}, 'intentDetectionConfidence': 1.0,
>   'languageCode': 'en'}, 'originalDetectIntentRequest': {'payload': {}},
>   'session': 'projects/agent_name-sit/agent/sessions/session-id'}

You want to perform some logic and build a response yourself, or add a context based on some logic or anything else.

```
response = json.dumps({
    'fulfillmentText': 'response from webhook'
    })
return response
```

You can check the fulfillment request and fulfillment response in the **Diagnostic Info** which you can access from bottom right corner of Dialogflow console when you send a test request from the console.